# Entity Framework performance inconsistency

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a method in my MVC application that is inserting the results of a survey using Entity Framework. The survey has around 70 questions and all of the results get inserted in one call to SaveChanges.

```
// mock code
public class SurveyService {
    public SurveyService(MyDbContext db) { ... }

    public void SaveSurvey(...) {

        foreach(var result in results) {
            db.Results.Add(new Result(...));
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I'm not calling SaveChanges in a loop. Just adding a bunch of entities and doing SaveChanges once. The code isn't extremely slow, but each INSERT is taking around 20 ms. When you have 70 entities that adds up to 1.4 seconds.

I can take this very same class in LinqPad (created a connection using the assembly) and do the following:

```
// in linqpad this refers to the context
var survey = new SurveyService(this);

survey.SaveSurvey(...);
```

Using the same exact web.config, pointing to the same database and saving the same results the saves each take around 2-3 ms. I have checked the Change Tracker and there aren't any differences between what is in the context and it's using the exact same code, so I'm not sure where the overhead is. I added database logging and can see pretty consistently that the queries are around 10x slower when running in the app.

What is causing this inconsitency in the performance?

Comment: Are you trying to measure performance using the debugger? or how?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with EF, it must be your SqlServer that may be facing high traffic.

Comment: What happens if you insert same data into SQL Server directly (just run insert queries in SSMS)? are there indexes needing rebuilt? triggers?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I measured the total time by using Stopwatch before / after SaveChanges(). The individual query times I am looking at the output from setting Database.Log.

Comment: @AkashKava That doesn't explain why it's different when executing on the site vs executing in LinqPad. It's using the same database. I'm not saying the performance is critical I'm just trying to understand why it's different. If there is something that's not running in LinqPad but is on the site that's adding overhead.

Comment: @trailmax It's the same database running for both the actual site and in LinqPad...so there shouldn't be any changes between the two. If I saw consistent times for both then that might make more sense.

Comment: Without a complete example, there is no way for us to verify, and/or diagnose the problem.  There could be assumptions you are making that are causing the problem, but because you don't tell us about them, we won't know.

Answer (score 0):

Rick Stahl discusses issues like this at http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/22/Entity-Framework-and-slow-bulk-INSERTs where he thinks the problem is the Change Tracking mechanisms in ef and presents some solutions to fix these problems

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's slower when running normally than when running in Linqpad. It's the same code using Entity Framework and the same database, yet LinqPad is 10x faster. The Change Tracking runs in both instances.